# How do I install tor on my ubuntu system?

Tags: 10.04, 64-bit, tor

I have Ubuntu 10.04 LTS 64 bit OS. How do I install tor so that it works and doesn't give me an error message? I got tor as an archive file (tar.gz) and I have an amdx64 architecture. I am new to linux as I am coming from a windows background. Please help.

Comment: What error messages do you get? Where did you get the tar.gz?

Answer (score 1):

1. Download https://www.torproject.org/dist/torbrowser/linux/tor-browser-gnu-linux-i686-2.3.25-6-dev-en-US.tar.gz (or more recent from https://www.torproject.org/projects/torbrowser.html.en )
2. Uncompress it.
3. Execute `start-tor-browser`
4. A dialog appears with a progress bar. After a minute or so a Firefox window will appear, it is anonymized.

Answer (score 1):

Just a little more description here but more or less saying same as above.

Open from the [tor website](https://www.torproject.org/download/download-easy.html.en#linux). Uncompress the file using the following command in a terminal window:

```
 > tar zxf tor-browser-gnu-linux-i686-2.3.25-6-dev-en-US.tar.gz
```

Then from the terminal type from the directory where you unzipped it (probably Downloads)

```
 > cd tor-browser_en-US
```

Where `cd` is the command you use to `change directory`

To run type

```
 > ./start-tor-browser
```